# Генерация цвета текста по фону

Tags: color, алгоритм, javascript

Такая задача: пользователь вводит два цвета, а скрипт после этого генерирует цвета, которые получаются при плавном переходе от первого цвета ко второму, и использует их в качестве фона. Далее нужно подобрать для каждого цвета фона наиболее различимый цвет текста. Очевидные варианты, которые мне не подходят: `fontColor=0xFFFFFF^rgbBgColor` (плохой результат для близких к серому цветов), `fontColorHue=rotate(bgColorHue, 180)` (плохой результат для близких к чёрному и белому цветов)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пока остановился на решении, использующем в качестве цвета текста белый, чёрный или жёлтый цвета. Также оно создаёт более или менее нормальную тень. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ckAQ6/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Просто переход от цвета к цвету - это слишком просто и не решает проблему сочетания цвета текста и цвета фона.

Изучи алгоритмы, уже реализованные в https://kuler.adobe.com/create/color-wheel/ и почитай вот это: [Цвета в web-дизайне: Выбор правильного сочетания для вашего сайта](http://habrahabr.ru/post/105250/) (ссылки в конце статьи).

Можно предложить цвет, но выбор всегда останется за пользователем.

Comment: Я упомянул переход между цветами лишь для предыстории задачи. И меня всё же интересуют более или менее конкретные идеи, а не отсылки к общей теории, отношение которой к данной проблеме весьма сомнительно.

Comment: Эта тема вообще сомнительна